# How do we pass a children element in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How can i pass HTML to a component like this in VueJS and render it in the component

```html
<my-vue-component>
  <div>
    ect...
  </div>
</my-vue-component>
```

Comment: Define a `<slot></slot>` within your `my-vue-component` definition.

Comment: thanks! i'll try that

Answer (score 0):

[Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) are the way to go!

Made even more dynamic by named slots where you can target various positions in the component.